# Setting up a progress bar in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have a program currently and have tried to implement a progress bar with my code. Bellow is an example of the code currently. The main GUI is in its own class and instantiates other classes to then execute code within those classes' methods. An example is as follows:

```
class MainClass {
    public javax.swing.JProgressBar progressBar;
    private void combineActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        Combine combiner = new Combine();
        combiner.Merge(folder);
    }
}
```

It takes a folder listing and then goes to the Combine class which  has the following code:

```
public class Combine extends SwingWorker<Integer,Integer>{
    public void Merge(Folder []){ (for int i=0;i<folder.length;i++){
        merge(folder[i]);

    }
    public void Merge(folder[]){
        output stream;
    }
}
```

How do I implement the swing worker properly in this example to make a progress update to the MainClass progress bar as each iteration of i occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin, your worker is missing some methods it should implement, such as `doInBackground()` and `done()`. You also need a constructor to pass `Folder[]`.

```
public class Combine extends SwingWorker<Integer,Integer>{

    Folder[] folders; 


    public Combine (Folder[] folders)
    {   this.folders = folders; }       

    private void Merge(Folder [])
    { (for int i=0;i<folder.length;i++)
        {
            merge(folder[i]);
            //Send the message of progress here, it will be executed
            //from doInBackground()
            setProgress(....);
        }

    }
    private void Merge(folder){
        output stream;
    }

    protected Integer doInBackground()
    {
        merge(folders);
        return null;
    }

    protected void done()
    { .... }
}
```

Then you would call this worker with

```
Combine combiner = new Combine(folders);
combiner.execute();
```

To track progress, this example is from `SwingWorker` [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html):

```
 combiner.addPropertyChangeListener(
     new PropertyChangeListener() {
         public  void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
             if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                 progressBar.setValue((Integer)evt.getNewValue());
             }
         }
     });
```

Comment: One thing is when I do this it, the doInBackground() method is called for every file that is in the array rather than just passing the array through the Merge method. Is there a particular reason why?

Comment: Hmm I don't see how that is possible unless you create multiple workers?

Comment: I solved it, had a lot of refactoring to do from my original code but it ended up making it even more functional. Thank you so much milez for your example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setProgress` method as you are doing your processing to send the update. You could simply count how many files there are and call `setProgress` with `(numberProcessed*100)/totalNumber`. Note that the multiplication is done first to prevent rounding issues.

This will cause the `PropertyChangeListeners` to be notified of the changes, this will happen on the EDT so it will be safe to update your `JProgressBar` from it.

Comment: Once I set the progress, where would I put the code to update the progress bar from that method?

Comment: As a `PropertyChangeListener`

Comment: So in the PropertyChangeListener I would put progressBar.setValue(i);?

Comment: Something like that yes. Where `i` is the value passed in the property changed event.

Comment: And would I put the Listener in my main class function or in the other class function?

Comment: Wherever it is most appropriate. Probably in the class containing the progress bar.